# Always hung on Vi, vim, but not nano when using company VPN

Tags: vpn, ubuntu-18.04, l2tp, vim, vi

I have a strange problem. IT changed the VPN to a newer Cisco device.
After connecting to the VPN, I can ssh to one of our corporate server.
I can `ls`, `cd`, `cat`, `sudo`.
**BUT** if I tried any editing using `vi` or `vim`
My terminal is just blank/black - seem to be hung.
`Nano` seems ok.

I'm currently using `Windows 10 + Cygwin` connecting to a `Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS`.
The VPN is using Windows 10 built-in `L2TP/IPsec with pre-shared key`

Before IT changed the VPN, editing seems to be ok. I notified IT, but they don't know what causing it.
What should I do/try to avoid this issue?

Comment: What's the value of $TERM when you start vi?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille `echo $TERM`
`xterm`

Comment: I was wondering if vi would be sending a control sequence that blocked your terminal, but with vim it should start a new window.  Is the sshd configured for X11 tunneling?  Do you start ssh with "-X" or "-Y" ?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I normally don't use -X nor -Y. Today I tested with -X and/or -Y still the same issue. 
`cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config |grep -i x11`
`X11Forwarding yes`
`#X11DisplayOffset 10`
`#X11UseLocalhost yes`
`#       X11Forwarding no`

Comment: vim should be started "nohup vim &", and your terminal should be available immediately, while vim should open in a new window.  Any errors will be reported to nohup.out.

Comment: In your ssh connection, does `echo $DISPLAY` return anything, or is it empty? I agree that it's a very odd problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very unfortunate that I stuck on this issue for quite sometime, but I managed to at least find the source of the problem.
Something or someone, changed the default stty.

I had to add `stty sane` into my `.bashrc` to reset it immediately after a login.
And after that vi/vim/nano seem to work fine. No random hangs anymore.